# Folder structure website php

Tags: php

Lets say I have the website url `www.example.com`. My index.php page is in the root directory. I then want to have a page at `www.example.com/someDir` as well as a page at `www.example.com/someDir/anotherDir`. I thought that I would make the directory `someDir` in the root directory and make the directory `anotherDir` within the directory `someDir`, then place an `index.php` page in both those new directories which would be the visible page at those URLs.

Is this the proper way?

Comment: Just trying it won't take you as long as composing this question ;-P

Comment: What makes you think there is but one _"proper way"_? .htaccess rewrites are just as viable. It's also very common to see a site with just one index.php file, that processes the requests and activates the bits and pieces of code required to send a response back. But yes: having a dir structure that reflects the uri's is an option, though make sure you take safety precautions

Comment: I did try it but its not working, however there is evidence to suggest there is another reason why this method is not working for me. I just wanted to make sure that I was theoretically going about it the right way

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Note that your web server (apache or whatever) should redirect `www.example.com/someDir` to `www.example.com/someDir/` (with a trailing slash) which will make the relative links work correctly with respect to the index.php files.